# Subsetting DataFrame based on column names of another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames and I want to subset `df2` based on the column names that intersect with the column names of `df1`. In `R` this is easy.

`R` code:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=rnorm(5), b=rnorm(5))
df2 <- data.frame(a=rnorm(5), b=rnorm(5), c=rnorm(5))

df2[names(df2) %in% names(df1)]
           a          b
1 -0.8173361  0.6450052
2 -0.8046676  0.6441492
3 -0.3545996 -1.6545289
4  1.3364769 -0.4340254
5 -0.6013046  1.6118360
```

However, I'm not sure how to do this in `pandas`.

`pandas` attempt:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.standard_normal((5,)), 'b': np.random.standard_normal((5,))})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.standard_normal((5,)), 'b': np.random.standard_normal((5,)), 'c': np.random.standard_normal((5,))})

df2[df2.columns in df1.columns]
```

This results in `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Index'`. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a true intersection, since `.columns` yields an Index object which supports basic set operations, you can use `&`, e.g.

```
df2[df1.columns & df2.columns]
```

or equivalently with [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html)

```
df2[df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns)]
```

However if you are guaranteed that `df1` is just a column subset of `df2` you can directly use

```
df2[df1.columns]
```

or if assigning,

```
df2.loc[:, df1.columns]
```

**Demo**

```
>>> df2[df1.columns & df2.columns]
          a         b
0  1.952230 -0.641574
1  0.804606 -1.509773
2 -0.360106  0.939992
3  0.471858 -0.025248
4 -0.663493  2.031343

>>> df2.loc[:, df1.columns]
          a         b
0  1.952230 -0.641574
1  0.804606 -1.509773
2 -0.360106  0.939992
3  0.471858 -0.025248
4 -0.663493  2.031343
```

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent would be:

```
df2[df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns)]
Out: 
          a         b
0 -0.019703  0.379820
1  0.040658  0.243309
2  1.103032  0.066454
3 -0.921378  1.016017
4  0.188666 -0.626612
```

With this, you will not get a KeyError if a column in `df1` does not exist in `df2`.